# Why can I not use a method to set text for a generic EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, settext

In a couple of places in my code, I've used a method to set the text of a view instead of directly setting it. What I mean is that rather than doing:

```
editText.setText(myString);
```

I've used a method as follows:

```
public void setText(EditText editText, String myString) {
     editText.setText(myString);
}
```

(Obviously this looks a little superfluous; I used this so I could check properties of the string that may have some impact on how I set the text in some cases.)

Using a method this way does not seem to set the text. Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: this is because it would be setting text to the variable that is passed not the one declared , variable = editext

Comment: I thought that what is passed to the method is a reference to that editText and as such any action performed on that reference should affect the originally declared variable?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted, the problem must be somewhere else. What exactly ist going wrong?

Comment: Hmm, just did another test and it seems you're right. I think that the variable I'm trying to input is null for some reason.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille You should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc yes thats correct, java is based on pass by reference, but then i just wrote the comment cz the variable names are the same.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Java is not pass-by-reference... And even if the above code has variables with the same name, it has the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Id of the element and then do set . 
For example

```
 EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_from_example);
 edtiText.setText("String");
```

Further more, if you want you can write seperate methods

it doesnt know to which editText to set the string.

Comment: How is this related to `why?`

Comment: I've done that. Thanks for trying to help but this isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: @publicstaticvoid you are sending two parameter know Have you initialized and it. without initialization or proper declaration we cannot able to set the value....

Comment: I've definitely initialized the edit text. If I had not, it would throw a null pointer exception.

However, I think you're correct in that the string is not initialized.

Comment: I've fixed it now thanks. Was some weird (and pretty stupid) onResume behaviour.